Married muslim, How do you deal with madzi in bed and prayer?
i am a married male. Frequently have intimacy with my wife in bed. I believe that semen is pure, but in the case of madzi/mazi, most scholar are in opinion that it is impure.
When married couple are having intimacy, of course they don't stay still, they're moving around. And madzi will be spread in the bed. Some can be seen, but others not since madzi is easily get dry overtime.
So how do you all perform prayer? especially Fajr? since after doing intimacy at night, couple will sleep in bed (either they do ghusl rightafter, or wait till the prayer times). And when sleeping/laying on the bed, the clothes (and body, hair, etc) will get stained by madzi that's spread around the bed.
Do you clean yourself and change clothes before praying? Do you have specific clothes for praying only?
Or do you change bedsheet after each intimacy?
Can you relate to this? Like i'm not the only married muslim in the world, there're so many. Yet it seems like they still pray normally, not thinking/having waswasa like i do.
